# Naming the csv file in write_df

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I am writing a file in sparkR using write_df, I am unable to specify the file name to this:

**Code:**

```
write.df(user_log0, path = "Output/output.csv",
         source = "com.databricks.spark.csv", 
         mode = "overwrite",
         header = "true")
```

**Problem:**

I expect inside the 'Output' folder a file called 'output.csv' but what happens is a folder called 'output.csv' and inside it called '*part-00000-6859b39b-544b-4a72-807b-1b8b55ac3f09.csv'*

What am I doing wrong?

P.S: R 3.3.2, Spark 2.1.0 on OSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the distributed nature of spark, you can only define the directory into which the files would be saved and each executor writes its own file using spark's internal naming convention.

If you see only a single file, it means that you are working in a single partition, meaning only one executor is writing. This is not the normal spark behavior, however, if this fits your use case, you can collect the result to an R dataframe and write to csv from that.

In the more general case where the data is parallelized between multiple executors, you cannot set the specific name for the files.

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding that even after collector also I cannot specify the name of the file?

Comment: Collecting and saving using the write command are two different things. When you use the write command you cannot specify the name of the file. When you collect, you basically transform the spark dataframe into a local (e.g. R) dataframe and from that point on you can do whatever you want with it (including saving it to csv by a name you choose). however, collecting to a local dataframe means you move everything to the driver and therefore lose all spark parallelism (everything must fit and be calculated locally).